# Sending the result of a mongoDB view to another collection ( INSERT....SELECT from SQL )

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I could create a big query, and turn it into a view. Let's call it DBA_VIEW.

```
db.DBA_VIEW.find()
```

I'm using noSQLbooster to interact with mongodb and I'm trying to insert the result of this view into another collection.

I don't want to "right click > export" because I need to do this via noSQLbooster itself.

I've seen some querie sthat can do the trick, but, as a SQL SERVER dba, I think I can't get the logic behind, let's say, this one below:

```
db.full_set.find({date:"20120105"}).forEach(function(doc){
   db.subset.insert(doc);
});
```

how can I use such approach to do my taks?

I just need the result of that view from a collection, to be inserted in another collection, then after this we are going to export the data into a .json file or even a .TXT.

Answer (score 2):

You can design the query in the following way so that the output is directly inserted in a new collection('subset' in this example) without iterating through the result set.

```
db.full_set.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            "date":"20120105"
        }
    },
    {
        $out:"subset"
    }
])
```

If 'full_set' has the following documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d423675bd542251420b6b8e"),
    "date" : "20130105",
    "name" : "Mechanic1"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d423675bd542251420b6b8f"),
    "date" : "20120105",
    "name" : "Mechanic2"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d423675bd542251420b6b90"),
    "date" : "20120105",
    "name" : "Mechanic3"
}
```

With the above query, the 'subset' collection would be having the following documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d423675bd542251420b6b8f"),
    "date" : "20120105",
    "name" : "Mechanic2"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d423675bd542251420b6b90"),
    "date" : "20120105",
    "name" : "Mechanic3"
}
```

Comment: It worked. I could isnert in a new collection ( it creates the collection ). Now I need to think how I can use `$merge` to insert new docs in this collection, since I don't have 4.2 version. Thanks.